# How to get array value from block to view file?

Tags: magento2

Block file

```
namespace Training\Contactus\Block;

class Main extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_formFactory;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Training\Contactus\Model\FormFactory $formFactory
   )
{
    $this->_formFactory = $formFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

  public function getTest()
  {
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $collection = $form->getCollection();
    return $collection;
  }
}
```

View file

```
 $coll = $block->getTest();
```

Getting error - Recoverable Error: Object of class AAA\BBB\Model\ResourceModel\Form\Collection could not be converted to string .

Please guide me>

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: @SohelRana - Yes, I cleared the cache

Comment: try after delete generation folder. Run this command  rm -rf var/generation/*

Comment: @PrincePatel - I tried, but no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data of that collection in your view file.

Try below code in your view file :

```
 $coll = $block->getTest()->getData();
```

Then do `Print_r($coll);`

Comment: No difference . Getting error - Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: post your full code !! then we got to know what is missing

Comment: I have updated Block file.

Comment: seems like code is ok , remove /var/generation directory , clear the cache and try again

Comment: Cheers !!! Glad to help